# HorizontalScrollView conflict with Recyclerview swipe android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontalscrollview, android-cardview

I'm using recycler view swipe to dissmiss and my cardview or recyler items contains the horizontal scroll view. Each time touch give prefrences to swipe to dismiss. Here is my code...Please tell how to separate the two swipes?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_feed_cardview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/activity_feed_image_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.workplains.androidapp.workmatec.LibraryClasses.CircularImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"
            android:id="@+id/task_feed_image" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_feed_timestamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/activity_feed_image_layout"
        android:text="9:15 PM"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/actionbar_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/task_feed_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Task By WorkMatec"
        android:padding="@dimen/two_dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/activity_feed_image_layout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/activity_feed_image_layout"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/activity_feed_timestamp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/task_feed_desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Task Description by the workmatec. New Task TAsk by the workmatec"
        android:padding="@dimen/two_dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/activity_feed_image_layout"
        android:layout_below="@id/task_feed_title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/task_feed_attachments"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:accessibilityLiveRegion="polite"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/activity_feed_image_layout"
        android:layout_below="@id/task_feed_desc">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/bt_ic_imageplaceholder"
                android:tint="@color/red"
                android:tintMode="src_in" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/bt_ic_imageplaceholder"
                android:tint="@color/red"
                android:tintMode="src_in" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

On the code, you have to add an `OnTouchListener` to the `HorizontalScrollView`. Then, when it receives an `ACTION_MOVE` event, you can disallow the parent view (in this case the `RecyclerView`) from capturing the horizontal scroll movement as a swipe:

```
HorizontalScrollView hScroll = [findViewById or whatever];
hScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Note that in the case where the contents of your `HorizontalScrollView` don't fill the full cell width (and therefore don't activate the horizontal scrolling) maybe you don't want to disallow the swipe. You can fix this by changing the `true` with a boolean that checks the width condition, something like:

```
horizontalScrollContents.measure(0, 0);
boolean lockSwipe = horizontalScrollContents.getMeasuredWidth() > cellWidth;
...
v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(lockSwipe);
```

Comment: OMG, this is so awesome. Struggled with this for a month and now I have a solution.

Comment: I was just about to drop swipe to delete and instead introduce a delete button when I stumbled upon this answer of yours. Two thumbs up, man! Worked as a charm!